# modifying multiple fields in a structured array (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a structured array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
fields = [('f1', np.float32), ('f2', np.float32)]
k = np.ones(2, fields)
```

I want to be able to access multiple fields and modify them simultaneously. I'm aware that I can access multiple fields using a view. But what I want to do is more like the following, where I take all the fields and modify them:

```
k[0] = k[0] * 2
```

But instead I get this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.void' and 'int'
```

Does anybody have an idea of what might work? The simpler the better - I have some rather large structured arrays that I need to perform these operations on. Best idea I can come up with is to assemble k[0] using a list comprehension from the field names, convert it to a tuple, and assign it back, but there might be more elegant solutions:

```
k[0] = tuple([k[0][name] * 2 for name in k.dtype.names])
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `dtype` like this, there are 2 direct ways of accessing and modifying the data.  By field name, e.g. `k['f0']`, or by elements (rows) in the form of tuples.  You are using the 2nd method.  If the number of fields isn't that large, and you need to access many elements, then the first is better.

But if the fields all have the same data types, you could do math on an equivalent 2d array.

```
In [937]: k = np.ones(5,fields)

In [938]: k2 = np.empty((5,2),dtype=np.float32)
In [939]: k2.data = k.data  # share the data buffers
In [940]: k2 *= 2   # do math on the 2d view
In [942]: k2[0] += 3
In [943]: k    # and see the effect via the shared buffer
Out[943]: 
array([(5.0, 5.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

A `view` works just as well

```
In [948]: k1 = k.view(np.float32).reshape(5,2)
In [951]: k1[1] = [3,4]
In [954]: k
Out[954]: 
array([(5.0, 5.0), (3.0, 4.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

But with a mixed dtypes, you may have to stick with the tuple comprehension.

If `k` has mixed types:

```
In [1025]: k
Out[1025]: 
array([(1.0, 1.0, b'1'), (1.0, 1.0, b'1')], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', 'S3')])
```

I can view the float fields with a list of names:

```
In [1027]: k[['f1','f2']][1]
Out[1027]: (1.0, 1.0)
```

but trying to modify those fields with a tuple does nothing (though there is no error).

```
In [1028]: k[['f1','f2']][1]=(2.0, 2.0)
```

Looks like I have to either set one field at a time, or all of one element via tuple.

If you need to do much math, don't break up an array into named fields any more than you have to.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your top solution, creating an array and filling it using the data command, but I tend to get the following error when I try to access the newly created array:

      TypeError: buffer is read-only

The weird thing is that it tends to work when I try to access it again?